# How to fix broken header in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, error-handling, xampp

I downloaded the files from a live site and launched it on my localhost for testing purposes. However, when I visit the page on localhost I see weird errors like broken header and weird characters as you can see in the images.

[image]
[image]

Is there a reason why this is happening? Has anyone gone through this before?

Comment: You need to check the the console errors. Is there any console error ?

Comment: No there are no errors in the console

Comment: No file missing ?

Comment: Do you have the DB and the files exactly ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have definitely seen this before.
Copy the files from your wp-config sample, paste on your wp-config.php and replace the database details accordingly.
Let me know if it works.

Comment: you are the genious of the day! appreciate the support

Answer (score 1):

I´ve enqountered this on occation when migrating from localhost to production. It´s usually because the DB character encoding does not match.